# take screenshot at start main activit

Tags: android

I went to create android application for crack and break screen and I think that I need to take a screenshot of launcher page in on create and save it and add effect of break in touch location.how I can take screen shoot in activity start to take launcher image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need screen shot
Just make the activity background transparent and use ontouchlistener for adding crack effect

Transparent background
[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

```
private void captureScreen() {
        View v = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "SCREEN"
                    + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Above code do the task of taking screen shot and saving it in png format in sdcard

call this code in `onCreate` function

---

**Methid 2**

On adb shell using below command you can take screen shot.

```
input keyevent 120
```

This command does not required any root permission so same you can perform from java code of android application also.

```
        Process process;
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent 120");
```

More about keyevent code in android see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Here we have used.  **KEYCODE_SYSRQ** its value is 120 and used for System Request / Print Screen key.